# RequestReadTimeout in htaccess gives 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: apache, .htaccess, timeout

I had timeout problems trying to upload large video files and none setting in php.ini and/or .user.ini solved it. The only way to solve the issue is by disabling reqtimeout_module at Apache conf file. Then everything worked fine, which means that my PHP settings are correct for large files.

But as I don't want to deal with Apache settings (Server or vHost), I'm trying with .htaccess file. The code below seems to be ok, I found it as solution to similar issues here. The problem is that it gives my 500 Internal Server Error when I'm adding it to .htaccess file.

What I'm doing wrong?

```
<IfModule reqtimeout_module>
RequestReadTimeout header=0
RequestReadTimeout body=0
</IfModule>
```

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_reqtimeout.html#requestreadtimeout: _“[Context](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/directive-dict.html#Context): server config, virtual host”_

Comment: Have read it many times but don't think that is related. I know how to disable reqtimeout_module in server side but I want to do it on runtime using .htaccess. Also the code that I wrote marked as solution at least in 2 questions here, but to me (as in some others) gives Internal Server Error.

Comment: _“Context: This indicates where in the server's configuration files the directive is legal.”_ - so when it says `server config, virtual host` for the context of the directive, then that means you CAN NOT use it in .htaccess.

Comment: Thank you. Didn't knew it. Strange that this code have been selected as solution before. Unless if that is a new rule.

Comment: Not sure what you are referring to exactly, but the context there probably wasn’t .htaccess then. This directive influences the TLS handshake, and that happens before the client and the server even speak HTTP with each other - but .htaccess applies after the request has been routed into the appropriate directory.